# What Maven dependency do I need for PowerMockRunner.class

Tags: maven, powermock, junit5

My test case includes the following line.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
```

Prior to upgrading to Junit 5 (Jupiter), I imported the following

```
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
```

But now with the later version of Junit, I can't find the dependency to import to incorporate PowerMockRunner into my test case.

I am requesting the Maven coordinates (groupId and artifactId) that will allow me to incorporate this class into my test case.

Comment: It looks like PowerMock doesn't support JUnit 5 yet. https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/830 is still open.

Comment: Just for the record: your question is probably off topic. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378712/are-maven-dependencies-off-site-resources